# Running node-cron blocks my terminal until I CTRL + C

Tags: javascript, cron

I writing a script to execute some POST methods using Axios. To execute it, I'm using node-cron and creating a job to execute it.

However, when I "node script.js", I see that my terminal isn't available, like it is still running or in a infinite loop.

The schedule task is working good, but I'm worried about the terminal thing. I'm not sure if when you create a task, it will run until the machine is rebooted or when you end the task using CTRL + C.

I'm not DEV, so this is the code that I did:

```javascript
const axios = require('axios');
const cron = require('node-cron');

let channelID = 'ID-HERE';

// let slackAPItopic = "https://letsdeel.slack.com/api/conversations.setTopic";
// let tokenSlack = 'token-here';
// let slackAPIsendMessage = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage";



const postInTopic = async (displayID) => {

    await axios.post(
        `https://letsdeel.slack.com/api/conversations.setTopic`, 
        {
            channel: channelID,
            topic: 'Shift Watcher from .JS:' + ' ' + '<@' + displayID + '>'
            
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer token-here"
            }
        }
    );

};

const privateMessage = async (displayID) => {
    await axios.post(
        `https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage`,
        {
            channel: displayID,
            text: "Hi! Just a reminder that you are on Shift Watch - From .JS"
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer token-here"
            }
        }
    );
};


var cronFirstHour = cron.schedule('0 1 * * 1,2,3,4,5', () => {
    
    let displayID = 'OADHWAD23';
    postInTopic(displayID);
    privateMessage(displayID);
    
},{
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "Atlantic/Azores"
}
);
```

Is it happening because that's how node-cron works? Like, a forever task? I was expecting to see the cron in the crontab or anything like.

I'm developing in MacOS at the moment, but the plan is moving to AWS. Or should I make it list like a service in Linux?

About the script: It will set the topic in Slack and send a message at the same time in a specific scheduled hour.

Comment: It's likely blocking because it's waiting to run your task.  This is identical behavior as any application that is not being run as an daemon.  If you're going to be using AWS you should take a look at [AWS cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)

Comment: @Tibrogargan and what if I make it run in the background as a service? Because it is running good, only the problem is that the terminal is blocked until I end its execution :(

Comment: You're over thinking it.  Node.js is intended to be used as a server processes.  Server processes (e.g. daemons) do not usually exit at all, they just sit in the background and do their thing.  You can get pretty much any node app to run in the background by running it (assuming you're using shell) like this: `node process.js&` instead of like this: `node process.js`.  For more info, search for "node daemon processes"